# Move box div around container div using jquery animate method

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am a student, new to jquery animation and trying to perform directional animation where there is a corresponding button for each direction and when any button is clicked the previous animation stops. I also don't want the smaller div to leave the bigger div no matter what button direction is clicked. I have setup HTML and CSS as follows.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Animation           
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="animate.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Animation in jQuery</h1>
        </header>
            <div id="btnPanel"> 
            <button id="button1">Up</button>  
            <button id="button2">Down</button>               
            <button id="button3">Left</button>               
            <button id="button4">Right</button>               
            <button id="button5">FadeOut</button>               
            <button id="button6">FadeIn</button>               
            <button id="button7">Blink</button>  
            <button id="button8">Reset</button>  

        </div>     

        <div id="container">
            <div id="box">
            </div>
            </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#container
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: powderblue;

}
#box
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;

}
```

**Edit**

I got all four directions working somewhat today (yay) but haven't gotten the hang of moving the box without it leaving the container. Here's that part of my Javascript file.

```
$(function MoveBox() {

    $("#button1").on("click", function MoveBox() {
        $("#box").animate({
            top: 150

        }, 1500)


    });

    $("#button2").on("click", function MoveBox() {
        $("#box").animate({
            bottom: 150

       }, 1500)
    });

    $("#button3").on("click", function MoveBox() {
        $("#box").animate({
            right: 150

        }, 1500)

    });

    $("#button4").on("click", function MoveBox() {
        $("#box").animate({

            left: 150

        }, 1500)

    });

});
```

I have been messing around with numbers inside each animate method for a few hours, and so far going right is the only one that seems to work as intended, the down direction has the box zooming outside the container and left goes other directions or doesn't work at all. Can someone show in code or explain the best way to get all four directions working more smoothly. I haven't done a lot of pixel math before now...

Comment: no need of `"` to wrap absolute in CSS,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not answer your question fully but might help point you in the right direction. I have put together two examples of how you can achieve what (I think) you're asking for.

The first (https://jsfiddle.net/Lda5mxej/) uses if/else statements to apply actions to each button.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'button1') { ... }
});
```

The other (https://jsfiddle.net/gkmey802/1/) attaches events/actions to specific buttons.

```js
$('#button1').on('click', function() { ... });
```

I have given two examples to help you understand the different approaches that can be taken to achieve the same result.